# Arrange an integer array such that no two consecutive numbers sum is divisible by 3

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A friend of mine came across this question in an online Assessment of a company and asked me this question.

> An array of integers is given and we have to (possibly) arrange the array such that no two consecutive numbers sum is divisible by 3.
>
> Size of the array `n<=10^5`.
>
> If no such arrangement is possible then we have to return `Not Possible`.

I could think of greedily filling integers such that consecutive element sum if not divisible by 3 that will give an `O(n^2)` solution (**BUT** I am not sure if greedily filling elements will give the solution here) or I could think of doing a (bruteforce) `DFS` by looking all possible arrangements but that would be an exponential time solution and certainly won't work here for the given array size condition.

Is there any `O(nlogn)` or `O(n)` solution possible for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes there exists O(n) solution:

1. First divide all element into 3 buckets, element `x` will belong to bucket `x mod 3`
2. Now we can use greedy strategy: notice that elements from buckets `1` and `2` cannot be neighbors, same for elements from bucket `0` and `0`
3. We can put all elements from bucket `1` into the answer, followed by one element from bucket `0` and all elements from bucket `2`
4. Now all that's left is some elements from bucket `0` which we can put between two elements of bucket `1` or  two element from bucket `2`
5. Of course there are some corner cases for which solution is impossible

Comment: There's a missing case: you can also add a 0 on the front or back (assuming the buckets 1 and 2 aren't empty). [0,1,0,2,0] is a test-case for this.

Comment: Coding this using constant additional space looks a useful exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm: Divide the numbers into three sets: Group 0 = 0 modulo 3, group 1 = 1 modulo 3, group 2 = 2 modulo 3. Let n0, n1, n2 be the number of elements in group 0, 1 or 2.

The elements of groups 1 and 2 must be separated by an element of group 0: If n0 = 0, and both n1 > 0 and n2 > 0, there is no solution. If n0 = 0, and either n1 = 0 or n2 = 0 or both, then nothing needs to be done.

Let n = n0 - 1. We need n elements of group 1 and group 2 to separate the items of group 0: If n > n1 + n2 there is no solution.

Now 0 ≤ n ≤ n1 + n2. Let m = min (n1, n). Start with n1 - m elements of group 1, followed by m pairs (element of group 0, element of group 1), followed by (n - m) pairs (element of group 0, elements of group 2), followed by the last element of group 0, followed by the remaining n2 - (n - m) elements of group 2.